# Harmony between react-templates, TypeScript, and webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, react-templates

I am trying to get [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), [react-templates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/), and [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to play together.

I started from the sample code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html. The `webpack.config.js` file contains

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

and `Hello.tsx` contains

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>;
    }
}
```

All required `npm` packages have been installed. When I run `webpack`, the application runs correctly.

If, after using `npm` to install `react-templates` and `react-templates-loader`, I added the following line to the `loaders` section of `webpack.config.js`

```
{test: /\.rt$/, loaders: ['react-templates-loader?modules=typescript']}
```

and updated the `extensions` section to include `.rt`. I extracted the embedded HTML from `Hello.tsx`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import template from "./Hello.rt"
// Also tried `import * as template from "./Hello.rt"`

export interface HelloProps {
    compiler: string;
    framework: string;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return template.apply(this);
    }
}
```

and `Hello.rt`:

```
<h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Hello.tsx
(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './Hello.rt'.

ERROR in ./src/components/Hello.rt
Module parse failed: node_modules/react-templates-loader/index.js?modules=typescript!src/components/Hello.rt Unexpected token (1:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:13)
```

plus a stack trace.

Is there any way to get TypeScript, react-templates, and webpack to play together? I found an example of using TypeScript with react-templates and grunt/browserify at https://github.com/bgrieder/react-templates-typescript-test, but I would rather use `webpack`.

Comment: where you success on this topic? I am having exactly the same problem! Thanks!

Comment: I have not gotten any further with this. I switched to Angular 2 and am having better luck.

Comment: I acomplished this creating a custom node program that imported the react-templates package and using glob to find the *.rt file inside the source folder I compiled them and write them back into folders

Answer (score 2):

I gave some hints here: https://github.com/wix/react-templates/issues/193

Basically switch back to `commonjs` modules and import in Typescript with `import template = require('./Hello.rt')`

Please let me know if the hints aren't enough and still need help.